# Como agrega estilos css los handlebars al ser renderizados con nodejs

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, handlebars.js, handlebars

Estoy aprendiendo nodejs y tengo una duda respecto con los motores de plantillas al ser renderizados, estoy trabajando con hbs, mi duda es si al ser renderizados mis archivos hbs que están en la carpeta views, estos son movidos o mostrados en la carpeta public desde el navegador?? Porque mis estilos css los tengo en la carpeta public, y a los archivos hbs que están en views al enlazarlos con los estilos css los tengo que enlazar como si estuvieran en la carpeta public para que funcionen, alguien me podría aclarar esta duda por favor, adjunto fotos para que se entienda mejor.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Te recomiendo mirar este video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o4njTeKjGWQ

Answer (score 1):

He tenido un problema muy similar y era por una cosa tan simple como corregir la siguiente linea de código...

```
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

A esta a continuación...

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

Este código debes de tenerlo en el archivo server.js. Los nombres de las variables de tú código, pueden variar con el mío, por lo que quizas el copiar y pegar no funcione.